# dmesg -T + how to expand dmesg info in order to verify history details

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel, dmesg

we have rhel 7.2 server

from `dmesg -T` we see only the current date - `Mon Jan 11`
and not history dates as `jan 10` , or less then `jan 10`

```
dmesg -T
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] Disabled fast string operations
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009ebff] usable
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009ec00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000dc000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000bfecffff] usable
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bfed0000-0x00000000bfefefff] ACPI data
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bfeff000-0x00000000bfefffff] ACPI NVS
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bff00000-0x00000000bfffffff] usable
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f0000000-0x00000000f7ffffff] reserved
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec0ffff] reserved
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fffe0000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000427ffffff] usable
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] SMBIOS 2.7 present.
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] DMI: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 12/12/2018
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] Hypervisor detected: VMware
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] vmware: TSC freq read from hypervisor : 2397.223 MHz
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] vmware: Host bus clock speed read from hypervisor : 66000000 Hz
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] vmware: using sched offset of 8561845015 ns
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] e820: last_pfn = 0x428000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] MTRR default type: uncachable
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021]   00000-9FFFF write-back
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021]   A0000-BFFFF uncachable
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021]   C0000-CBFFF write-protect
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021]   CC000-EFFFF uncachable
[Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021]   F0000-FFFFF write-protect
    [Mon Jan 11 12:02:53 2021] MTRR variable ranges enabled:
.
.
.
.
.
```

what is the dmesg setting or dmesg changes that we need to do in order to expand the dmesg details and see also dmesg info?

Comment: [How to increase dmesg buffer size in CentOs 7.2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412182/how-to-increase-dmesg-buffer-size-in-centos-7-2)

Comment: `dmesg` entries are stored in memory and do not persist between reboots. This is why they are also logged. Use your logs to see messages from before you rebooted.